# 'Delete' user but keep records (foreign keys)

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, foreign-keys

I have a table `users` with user accounts (user_id, username, ...). The user_id is related to multiple other tables - e.g. a table with his last actions, profile details, his products, his interests etc.

Sometimes a user wants to be deleted, and then I set a field 'deleted' to 1. The records in most of the tables should be deleted, but the records in 2 tables (`reports` and `messages`) should keep the reference to the user. Reason: For example, a message partner still wants to see the username of the account he recently talked to. What is the best way to do this?

**1)** In PHP store the ids of the records in `reports` and `messages` that should be kept in an array. Then delete the user. Automatically all the tables related to `users` delete their records with a reference to the deleted account. The reference in `reports` and `messages` should be: `ON UPDATE SET NULL` so their records still exists after user delete. The database is clean now, then re-insert the user with the same user_id with the field 'deleted' to 1. Then update the data in the array to the user_id so the reference is set again.

**2)** Remove the references to the user in `reports` and `messages` (so there are no foreign keys).

**3)** ... (is there a better option?)

Thanks!

Comment: surely, rather than all that just set the "ON DELETE" to "NO ACTION" for the user_id column references in the two tables mentioned?

Comment: please check my  answer and replay did it worked or not

Comment: Why don't you just `1) Flag the user as deleted` and `2) Delete the records one table at a time for each table that needs to be cleaned up`. This should IMHO be done in the PHP code so that a future coder would know what happens when you click the `Delete user` button. Cascading deletes are, once again IMHO, very risky. **Abhik's** answer suggests using a trigger, and that might be a good enough solution. But a trigger based solution is quite well hidden from a coder working on the PHP code so it might be confusing - How exactly are the tables being cleaned up by setting `deleted = 1`..?

Comment: The tables were being cleaned up by deleting the user (so the foreign keys caused the deletion of the data in the tables) and then I re-inserted the user with `deleted=1`.

Comment: Does everything actually need to be deleted or could you use the same `deleted = 1` method for each of your tables and just implement on those that are supposed to be "deleted"? Then you could check for `deleted === 1` property on each object/result and deal with it at runtime rather than delete it and be stuck with the loss.

Comment: hello are you still in search of answer ?

Comment: It's much clearer for me now. Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1) I would **never** think to delete the user record and leave other tables that contain user data with no existent user_id in the user table.  As you mentioned there are plenty of reasons that you have to keep the user account.

```
  And you only need 1 simple UPDATE status query.
```

(So I would keep the foreign key and there would be no DELETE case on this table).

2) There would be some cases that you have to delete this data from your database (e.g. legal issues, millions of deleted users). An alternative to this would be to **create a deleted_users table**, with user_id and username and create a function to check if user is deleted.

But I think, this method in a production level environment would be error-prone and I would not recommend it at all. In this case **foreign key** is not kept

```
You need 2 queries (INSERT, DELETE) and 1 query (SELECT) every time you have to check whether a user is deleted.
```

*To sum up: the option 1 (**status: deleted**) is the best choice.  This way you can also recover the data when the user changes his mind.*

*PS: In case you are in a development stage and you want to delete some users from a lot of tables, you can just create a delete function and a loop with the tables. Sth like this:*

```
$tables=array('table1','table2','table40');

function delete_user_from_table($table,$user_id){
    //connection db
    //delete query
    $deleteQuery=$db->query("DELETE FROM {$table} WHERE user_id='{$user_id}");
if($deleteQuery){echo $user_id.' deleted from table '.$table;}
    }

//delete loop   
foreach ($tables as $table){
    delete_user_from_table($table,'23');
}
```

***But, in this case, I wouldn't create a foreign key for just development level usability.***

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm deleting records I'm sure I never need. For example user actions or user products after his permanent account delete. Is that ok? So I'm NOT deleting the user (I only flag it as deleted) but I delete any associations with it. The only thing with the trouble are the two tables `reports` and `messages`...

Comment: updated grammatical mistake that may confused you.Not a good idea to delete and re-insert and so on.

Comment: Thanks, looks great! The reason why I did a re-insert is because I want to delete the user data in around 40 other tables. When I have a reference to them they would automatically be deleted. Then I re-inserted the record with the user. It's not possible with your solution because I don't delete anything. When I need to clean the database, should I run 40 delete queries for the tables where I want to delete some data?

Comment: @Jordy, if you want to maintain referential integrity and not actually delete the user record, you will need to "run 40 delete queries". However, if you wanted it to behave similar to a foreign key cascade, you could implement a "CleanProfile(user_id)" stored function to collect all the DELETEs in one place, and call it from an AFTER UPDATE trigger on the user table whenever `deleted` is set to 1.

Comment: @Uueerdo. Thank you, I understand! Why is it for the database better to have no `ON DELETE CASCADE` and run 40 delete queries after a account delete only to prevent a re-insert? Isn't it better to have ON DELETE CASCADE on 40 tables, and delete and re-insert the user for the two tables 'messages' and 'reports'?

Comment: @Jordy, you'd have to reproduce ALL the data removed by the cascade that you wanted preserved. In this case, you are not really wanting to delete the user, just their "personal" information; you're just trying to shortcut by DELETEing the user. There is nothing wrong with CASCADE when it is "the right thing to do". ;)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So in summary, you mean my shortcut is ok if I reproduce it for two tables? (I just set the user_id tot NULL, I remember the records in PHP and update them again after the re-insert), or is that in fact wrong and should I use a CleanProfile() function for 40 tables and no CASCADES as you mentioned?

Comment: @Jordy - I think Nikos is saying *don't* use CASCADE, just set deleted to 1, and use his suggested function to remove the data you actually want to remove. I would have to agree if so. If you do go down the route of holding the data in memory in PHP, be careful about your transaction handling so you don't lose a lot of data if the system crashes or loses connection! Also, if messages and reports can hold a lot of data for one user, it might not be very quick to pull that all in to memory and then save it back out again.

Comment: I would go for option 1 but with some tweaks. a) Instead of a boolean, make deleted a timestamp field so you can check later if you need to purge stuff from the DB b) make sure you are obfuscating enough data from the user profile (i.e. username, e-mail...) so you will not accidentally send emails to deleted users, they will be able to re-register and if there is any leak, you won't be liable for storing their personal data.

Answer (score 5):

The reason to use a foreign key constraint on the `reports` and `messages` tables is to enforce referential integrity; normally that's a good thing but in this case it's the source of your problem, because you actually WANT to violate referential integrity in order to maintain an audit trail after deleting a `users` record. I suggest you remove the foreign key constraint on the `user_id` columns in the `reports` and `messages` tables. That will allow you to delete a user without impacting the data in the reports or messages tables. Unfortunately, a `user_id` is not useful without a corresponding username, so instead of storing the `user_id` you'll be better off storing the username in the reports and messages tables directly. In this case I suggest that you alter the database schema as follows (this is pseudocode and may need to be adapted for MySQL syntax):

```
ALTER TABLE reports ADD COLUMN username VARCHAR;
UPDATE reports FROM users SET reports.username = users.username
    WHERE reports.user_id = users.user_id;
ALTER TABLE reports DROP COLUMN user_id;

ALTER TABLE messages ADD COLUMN username VARCHAR;
UPDATE messages FROM users SET messages.username = users.username 
    WHERE messages.user_id = users.user_id;
ALTER TABLE messages DROP COLUMN user_id;
```

Notice that the new `username` columns are not foreign keys on the `users` table.

For performance reasons you may also want to add indexes to the `username` columns in these tables if you will be running select statements that include the `username` in the where clause.

By the way, in my experience, it often makes sense to remove the `id` column from user tables altogether and make the username the primary key on the `users` table, assuming the `username` values are all unique.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a better option.

If you need the user for any reason don't delete it, basic rule. Do the deleted=1 update and remove any data in the tables that you need to delete. Keep the referential integrity as you have it right now, this will alert you if you try to delete more than you intended. A few delete from table_name where id_user = XXX will save you a lot of trouble now and in the future. You have those foreign keys for a reason. Trust me.

Of course you need a backup policy in place just in case you were wrong about the "wont need it anymore" sentence.

Comment: So I have to delete the user data manually and not automatically by foreigns?

Comment: In this case, absolutely yes, although i guess you have a way to automate this (script, desktop app, etc.) Option 1 and 2 are error prone and far from elegant.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all to be handled from the database level then you can use trigger to do the job.
For kepping the data in `reports` and `messages` data even if the user is deleted = 1 meaning these data 
will be there for other reference and when you add a new user details with the same `user id` everything will
be reset. The process looks more like a CRM application where the data is never deleted even users, only its set to `deleted=1`
When a new user is introduced for that deleted record the other likned data are auto-matically get assigned to this user.

However in your case you still want to delete some data. So using following trigger it could be done.
Note that you are not deleting an user you are updating the user.

```
delimiter //

create trigger user_update after update on user
for each row
begin
  if old.deleted <> new.deleted then 
    if new.deleted = 1 then
      delete from last_actions where user_id = new.user_id ;
      delete from profile_details where user_id = new.user_id ;
      -- all the delete queries where you want to delete
    elseif  new.deleted = 0 then
      delete from reports where user_id = new.user_id ;
      delete from messages where user_id = new.user_id ;
    end if ;
  end if;
end;//

delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am giving two option first one is to stopping the row deleted from `reports` and `message` table but i think this will not solve your problem because if the row deleted from user table you can't get his name email or anything else.

**solution 1**
Please delete the constraint on both `reports` and `messages` table by doing this is a referenced user is deleted from the user table no action will be perform on these table

**solution 2**
make status column in users table so instead of deleting the row set it false and this false means that further activity can be perform by this user.